# Lagrangian for a moving spring device

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, spring

[image: two masses moving at different velocities at the same direction.]

How can I write the proper Lagrangian for such as system as the one shown in picture?

Am confused about what is the suitable way to designate the coordinate.

Comment: What coordinates would you use if the spring weren't there?

Comment: The horizontal one, x

Comment: There are two blocks, so you'll probably want at least two coordinates. Usually one would label these $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Also, is the spring connecting the blocks or not? The drawing makes it look like one of the blocks runs into the other block.

Comment: can I subtract their velocities and consider one to be standing still,let's say m2 , while the other is moving toward it ?.

Comment: yea it's right, m1 is running into m2 and m2 by itself aslo moves to the right at lower velocity than m1 does.

Answer (score 2):

We use the coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$ for the two blocks. Let $\ell$ be the natural length of the spring. Let us now write down the potential for this system. Note that if $x_2 - x_1 > \ell$ then the spring does not exert any force on either block and hence there is no potential. If $x_2 - x_1 < \ell$, then the spring is compressed with $\Delta x = \ell - (x_2 - x_1)$. The potential in this case is $\frac{1}{2} k (\Delta x)^2$. We can then write the full potential as
$$
V(x_1, x_2) = \frac{1}{2} k \left( \ell - x_2 + x_1 \right)^2 \theta (\ell - x_2 + x_1) 
$$
where $\theta(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. The Lagrangian is then
$$
L = \frac{1}{2} m_1 {\dot x}_1^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_2 {\dot x}_2^2 -  \frac{1}{2} k \left( \ell - x_2 + x_1 \right)^2 \theta (\ell - x_2 + x_1) 
$$

Comment: Is is possible that $x_2 - x_1 < 0$? You should put an infinite potential to prevent it.

Comment: Assuming that $m_1$ and $m_2$ are really point masses, I don't see why they cannot pass through each other thus giving $x_2 < x_1$. If that is an additional requirement, then yes, we should put an infinite potential to prevent it. (Actually not necessarily infinite, simply something thats larger than the initial energy of the system)

Comment: @Prahar It really should be infinite. You can't guarantee an upper bound on the kinetic energy, so you can always overcome a finite potential with sufficient initial velocity.